# Remote debugging golang application in aks cluster using Cloud Code and GoLand

Tags: go, debugging, azure-aks, goland, google-cloud-code

I'm trying to debug a go application in AKS cluster using Cloud Code and GoLand IDE.

How should I use it to debug remote go application **without building and pushing each time docker file to remote registry**?

Comment: If you are looking for hot deployment during development, telepresence helps you to run the service from your dev box. This local service will join the cluster using proxy. https://www.telepresence.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Neta Refua for the feedback. We are working on hot reloading for Go in GoLand IDE, it will be in Cloud Code Insiders build in few weeks. Please feel free to join our [insiders group](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/intellij/insiders) for notifications when the feature is available and give us feedback about the feature. Please use [Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-code-intellij/issues) to file any bugs/feature requests that you may need.

We have this feature [hot reloading](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/vscode/yaml-editing#enabling_skaffold_file_sync_and_hot_reloading) in VSCode/Cloud Code release incase if you want to try out hot reloading there.